# How to use JSX/HTML code in Data() Vue 3 components with VITE

Tags: vue.js, jsx, vite

I am create a design system using rollup.js, Vue 3.

I have a component which outputs the contents of the array

```
<template v-for="item, index in testData" :key="index">
  <DsJsx :render="item" />
</template>
```

testData:

```
data() {
 return {
  testData: [
    {
      testBlock:
      <div>
        <b>Column name 2</b> // <-- html code
      </div>,
    },
  ],
};
```

},

**DsJsx.vue**

[image]

**And this code works correctly.**

But when I try to use this component in Vite.js I get this error.

What should I do so that I can use html in the data in the Vite project?
[image]

Comment: This syntax is wrong:
`v-for="item, index in testData"` should be `v-for="(item, index) in testData"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to *vite.config.js*

```
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx';
.....
plugins: [
    vueJsx({}),
],
```

and `lang="jsx"` to `<script>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid syntax for Vue `render` function, are you sure that **DsJsx.vue** display text from **testBlock** ?

Below is valid example:

**testData**

```js
....
// As string
testBlock: "<div> <b>Column name 2</b> </div>"
....
```

**DsJsx.vue**

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    element: String,
  },
  render(h) {
    return h("div", {
      domProps: { innerHTML: this.element }
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The screen shows what DsJsx gets in this case
https://ibb.co/6B2s3V9

Comment: Anyway, can you try may example ?